# Limiting read access in postgres to few rows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

We have a requirement where we want to limit the maximum no. of rows that a select query can return when its done using a particular login. So basically we would like to append a limit clause to any select query fired by a particular user.

Is this possible in PostgreSQL? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: Only way i know is force user to use views.

create view test as select * from table limit 100 

now, default search_path is $user,public.  you could create $user schema ( where $user is username) and create views there with limit and remove users access to other schemas (public)

Comment: How users access DB, Is it through a application layer like php... etc?

Comment: This will be possible with the upcoming 9.5 through "row level security": http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createpolicy.html

Answer (score 3):

You can define a function that returns required limit for some users. The function below set limit for users `joe` and `ben`.

Note that `limit null` is equivalent to `limit all`, so all other users will have no limits.

```
create or replace function set_limit()
returns integer language sql as $$
    select case current_user 
        when 'joe' then 100
        when 'ben' then 200
        else null
    end
$$;

select * from some_table limit set_limit();
```

Edit:

> So basically we would like to append a limit clause to any select query fired by a particular user.

Once function set_limit() is created you can append `limit set_limit()` to any select query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in this case isn't it up to the user to call that function in their query. They are still free to select all without using the function. I want to force the limiting without the need for any intervention from the person executing the query.

Comment: You cannot limit a user if he can execute unrestricted queries. If you are going to restrict users, queries should be done in your application.

Comment: @klin You definitely can.  Our application users are only able to call functions, they have no direct access to any table.  The functions are defined with `SECURITY DEFINER` by a suitable user.

Comment: @dezso - "Our application users are only able to call functions" - so they cannot execute unrestricted queries.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, when a user writes `SELECT * FROM thetable`, and `thetable` is a base table (not a view), it is *not* possible to restrict number of rows returned.

It *is* possible for `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` (with triggers and shared memory).